# Jquery delegation on jquery collection/domRef but selector string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario where I have actual dom reference to dom element and want to delegate event to that dom reference.

```
var domRef = $('.selector');
// I want something like this.
$(document).on('click', domRef, function() {

});
```

I know it makes no sense to use it this way in the above code but I have a used case for myself where I want such functionality. I would appreciate can provide me solution without debating on the reason for following such practice.

Comment: And...this didn't work? What went wrong?

Comment: When you say "dom reference" do you mean a jQuery collection or an actual DOM node? (Your code suggests the former.)

Comment: it fire the callback if I click outside the domRef. domRef is an object and not a selector string.

Comment: @Mathletics, yes I meant the same thing

Comment: What's wrong with `domRef.on('click', domRef, function() {});` ? Please explain a little further if that's not enough

Comment: @PabloGonzálezAlba why would you try to delegate to the same object?

Comment: @PabloGonzálezAlba, I am passing a reference to dom collection and not a selector string.

Comment: To be clear, the syntax you have above would delegate events **from** your DOM node **to** the `document` level; I know you don't want to discuss it, but I cannot imagine why you would need to do that when you already have the target selected.

Comment: @Mathletics, I don't want to bind events on bunch of elements.

Comment: @Mathletics sorry, I meant `domRef.on('click', function() {});`. @emphaticsunshine this revised code should trigger each time a click is made in an element inside domRef, i understand that's what you wanted to do. Maybe I'm missing something then

Comment: @PabloGonzálezAlba, I know domRef.on('click', function() {}); will trigger event on domRef but it will be binding event to domRef element and not at document level.

Comment: @emphaticsunshine I got it, I confused the `on()` funcionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

> **`.on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )`**
>
> selector: **A selector string** to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is `null` or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

The `selector` needs to be a string. If it is not then it is considered to be the parameter `data`. You can confirm this [by looking at `.on()`'s source code.](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.fn.on)

A workaround may be doing something like:

```
var $domRef = $('.selector');
```

```
$(document).on('click', function(evt) {
  if($domRef.is(evt.target)) {
    ...
  }
});
```

Even though, performance-wise it is not so good.

Comment: Thank you. This is pretty close but it has performance issues. So I think I will send a selector in options.

Comment: This is exactly the same as my answer and came later. Why did this get accepted?

Comment: Unfortunately for me, you happened to post faster but not explaining it properly. I suppose the explanation made a difference for the OP. Anyways, he's the only one that knows

Comment: @Mathletics, I thought Alexander replied first as his reply was showing before yours and I can mark only 1 answer as correct. Alexander also did post documentation which explains he did some more work.

Comment: @emphaticsunshine, if you by any chance can modify `domRef`. You can store store the selector as in `$('.selector').data('selector', '.selector')` to use it on later. But, my answer relies that you can't do that

Comment: There are times listed on the answers, and that documentation is irrelevant, but ok.

Comment: @Alexander, Thank you for thinking for different solutions but I don't want to keep dependencies on data attributes.

Comment: @Mathletics, I am sorry if it offends you.

Answer (score 2):

Just handle the delegation manually:

```
var domRef = $('.selector');

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    // test if the click target is the same as your domRef
    if ($(e.target).is(domRef)) {
        // do special stuff for this node
    }
});
```

Comment: Delegating to the `document` is a terrible for performance, so I wouldn't get too worked up over micro-optimizing this mess.